# Which is preferred here - uitableview or uibutton?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, uibutton, xib

[image]So, I'm almost done with the functionality part for the app I'm developing and now the graphic designer gives me a png image I have to match the xib to. The image has a 'search agent' section with select country,region,language,type of property and two textfield. Originally in my xib I had separate buttons for each and two textfileds, and the button action would give me pickers to select country, region etc. So the png requires me to put all these into a tableview. Is creating tableview with buttons and textfields better or having them separately on the view itself? I know this is not a programmatic doubt in specific but I really need to know which is better. This is my first ever app and I'm really clueless.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what you want, often people like to use tableviews simply because they group the elements nicely, this is very common in login screens for instance.

But that does not mean one is better than the other is really just a design choice. That being said having buttons inside tableviews can create issues at times, since the response chain is in the tableview and in the button.

For your case I would recommend not to use a uitableview.

Comment: Can you please see the png..I just edited my question now. Does it not require a lot of complicated stuff having buttons and textfields within the table, extracting the text from textfields ,button actions etc Should I still go with tableview?

Answer (score 0):

IF you have a group of similar controls such as 5 buttons 2 text fields and etc.. use table view

If they are not divided to groups use buttons and textfields normally

Answer (score 0):

From the png it seems that the use of table view is good enough as the required functionality is easily completed with tabelView. So I preferred the tabelView

Comment: The right arrow at the end of the row generally means the view navigates to another view right? Here I have pickers. So is it still okay to use this png?

Comment: yes this is perfectly right you can show pickers in action sheets